# get & set element height in angularJs in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to get & set height of an element via custom directive. 
here's the code.

```
app.directive('height', function(){
return{
link: function(scope,element,attr){
var getHeight = element.css('height'); // first method
var getHeight1 = element.css('offsetHeight'); // second method
}
}}) 


<div height style="height: 50px">test</div>
```

Is is possible to call a directive on every click.

Comment: `element[0].addEventListener('click',function($event){
     
    })`

Comment: Please make it clear how do you want to set the height. And where you wan to get the height.